# Replace single and double quotes prefixed with backward slashes

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Folks,

I have been trying to get a sed command which will replace `\'` to `'` and `\\"` to `\"` in a file. I tried the below using `sed` but am not able to figure out how to segregate single and double quotes.

```
$ cat temp
\'
\\"

$ cat temp | sed 's#\\\\"#\\"#' | sed 's#\\'#'#'
'
"
```

desired output is

```
'
\"
```

Can someone point out what i am doing wrong.

Note: I want to apply this change to all the occurrence in the file

Comment: you cannot use `'` inside single quotes like that.. use `\x27` instead.. `sed 's#\\\x27#\x27#'`

Comment: Do you need all `\\ ` to be reduced to `\ `, or just those followed by double-quotes?

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ gsub(/\\\047/,"\047",$0); gsub(/\\\\\042/,"\\\042",$0) }1' temp
```

The output:

```
'
\"
```

Comment: Looks like this work. Let me  test it and then i will accept this as the answer ! . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With any sed on any UNIX box:

```
$ sed 's/\\'\''/'\''/g; s/\\\\"/\\"/g' file
'
\"
```

with GNU or OSX sed for EREs enabled with `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's/\\('\''|\\")/\1/g' file
'
\"
```

Comment: Great solution Ed as usual. I would like to ask you a question how to become like Ed one day may be I could become expert like you :)

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, all it takes is 38 years of programming experience :-).

Answer (score 0):

Tested with `GNU sed 4.2.2`, not sure about portability
I've modified input sample to show working of command better:

```
$ cat temp 
\' and \\' and \\\'
\" and \\" and \\\"

$ sed -E 's/\\([\x27"])/\1/g' temp 
' and \' and \\'
" and \" and \\"
```

- `-E` use ERE, some `sed` versions use `-r`
- `\\([\x27"])` will match `\` followed by `'` or `"` and the quote character alone is captured
- `\1` the captured group is used as replacement
- `g` modifier will replace all such occurrences in line

To change only `\\"` and not any occurrence of `\"`

```
$ sed -E 's/\\\x27/\x27/g; s/\\\\"/\\"/g;' temp 
' and \' and \\'
\" and \" and \\"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\\\(\\['\''"]\)/\1/g' file
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/\\(\\['\'"])/\1/g' file
```

The problem is the single quote is used to quote the sed expression and therefore needs to be quoted in the shell hence `\'`. Using a character class for the single quote or the double quote allows the substitution to use a back reference and hence simplify the righthandside of the substitution.

Comment: Those wouldn't convert `\'` to `'` as the OP wants.

Answer (score -2):

One of the difficulties you have is that you're writing your expression as a command-line argument to sed, and hence need to quote it for your shell.  It's much easier if you write your sed program in a file:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -f

s/\\'/'/g
s/\\\\"/\\"/g
```

You need to double each `\` to quote them to the `s` command, but there's no extra quoting that the shell would require.

Demonstration:

```sh
$ cat 44649501.input

\'
\\"

$ ./44649501.sed <44649501.input 

'
\"
```